# How to click browser 'stop' button using Webdriver IO

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

Little background info: The program I am testing rests inside another website behind a login wall. As soon as you verify password and log in, you can type the direct link to the screen I need to test without having to click through the website. The problem I am having, as soon as I log in, my automated test will wait until the first page to load (sometimes up to 40 seconds) before continuing the test. I have tried using browser.keys("Escape") but that isn't working.

Is there any way to use WebdriverIO to simulate the stop button being pressed or a console command I can execute?

Here is a snip of the code I am using for reference.

```
    // Log into website as user
    browser.waitForVisible(Username, timeout)
        .setValue(Username, "User")
        .setValue(Password, "Password")
        .click(LogInButton)

    // Switch to test website
    .pause(2000)
        .keys('Escape')
        .url(URL)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot press a stop button, because it is a browser button.
WebDriver supports only web page elements, it cannot iteract with browser's controls (buttons, menu options etc).

But you can try a workaround - don't use WebDriver's click() method to click on the login button, but send ENTER key to this button instead.

In java it looks like:

```
findElement( loginButton ).sendKeys( Keys.ENTER );
```

instead of:

```
findElement( loginButton ).click();
```

Here is javaDoc of this method:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-

click() method clicks on element, then waits for page to load, while sendKeys( Enter ) doesn't wait, only sends a keystroke and continues execution.
Enter key sent to the button just "press" this button.
In this way your test will not wait for page reload, and will continue immediately.